# How to load javascript from a CDN with a local fallback in the <head>

Tags: javascript, external, cdn, fallback, head.js

I want to use [Head JS](http://headjs.com/) to dynamically load all of the other scripts for my pages.  I'm planning on using the version hosted by [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.com) to take advantage of the better caching, decreased latency, etc.

I have no reason to think CDNJS is going anywhere, but even for Google CDN hosted files like jQuery, I like to include a fallback.  When I'm using jQuery though, the files are included at the end of the `<body>` tag.  Due to the nature of Head JS, I need to include it in the `<head>` of my page.

In the `<body>` I would use two lines like this:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/0.96/head.min.js"></script>
<script> window.head || document.write('<script src="js/libs/head-0.96.min.js"><\/script>') </script>
```

Can I use this same set of lines in the head as a fallback?  Won't `document.write()` overwrite my entire page?  Don't scripts load differently when they exist in the `<head>` due to the order that browsers parse the DOM?

I'm still pretty new to this, so any guidance would be hugely helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: document.write only destroys your document if you try doing it AFTER the page load has completed. An in-line document.write will execute as the page's loaded/parsed and simply insert the written data into the document as is.

Comment: yes, but won't the Head JS load calls that are in the `<head> fire _before_ the script loads from a document.write?

Comment: only if you marked the previous script tag as `async`. Otherwise scripts are loaded synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably already know, you won't be testing for `window.jQuery` but some function included in head.js.

Additionally, you're right that you may not want to use `document.write()` twice here.

Instead of `document.write()`, try this:

```
function appendScript(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var theScript = document.createElement('script');
  theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  theScript.src = url;
  theScript.onreadystatechange = callback;
  theScript.onload = callback;
  head.appendChild(theScript);
}
```

For the url, use your local fallback.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the jQuery part!  I'll give this one a shot!  How to I set up the callback to run the `head.js()` commands after the Head JS is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know much about head.js but I don't know if you could guarantee this would run before or after head.js by design.